# Inserting same auto_increment id into two different tables

Tags: java, mysql, sql, auto-increment

I am using two tables in a database. First table is to store personal details of students where one column is auto_increment named as Student_id. I have another table for storing subject details which also contains Student_id which has foreign key relations with previously mentioned column.

How can I use the same id value for both table. Now I am using java PreparedStatement to send query separately for updating both tables (without ids). like,

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("query");
preparedStatement.setString(i,"parameter");
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

I have done the same thing for two tables, but is it possible to update with the same auto_id in both table? Can some one help with java implementation.

Db schema is as follows:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no table name mentioned, I'm considering the table name being used as `ParamsTable` and here is the flow!

You do an insert as mentioned in your code (posted in the question)!

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("query");
preparedStatement.setString(i,"parameter");
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

After this, you will have to fire a `SELECT` query to get the last inserted id (the auto-incremented id) from your `ParamsTable`

```
ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery("SELECT last_insert_id() AS last_inserted_id");
String lastInsertedID = resultSet.getString("last_inserted_id");
```

You will now be holding the last inserted id of the auto_increment column, which  you could use further in any table of your choice!

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am maintaining foreign key relation between both ids, I got error like, "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails". How can we solve it?

Comment: Please add your table structure for better understanding!

Comment: Sorry , Added now :)

Comment: Can it be added with same value in both tables?

Comment: I think NO, your table design isn't the greatest - Why do you want to hold data about the same student in two different tables with the same StudentId?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("query");
preparedStatement.setString(i,"parameter");
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
ResultSet generatedKeys = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys()
if (generatedKeys.next()) {
    user.setId(generatedKeys.getLong(1));
}
```